# Modify values programmatically SPSS

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I have a file with more than 250 variables and more than 100 cases. Some of these variables have an error in decimal dot (20445.12 should be 2.044512).

I want to modify programatically these data, I found a possible way in a Visual Basic editor provided by SPSS (I show you a screen shot below), but I have an absolute lack of knowledge.

- How can I select a range of cells in this language?
- How can I store the cell once modified its data?

[image]

--- EDITED NEW DATA ----
Thank you for your fast reply.

The problem now its the number of digits that number has. For example, error data could have the following format:

Case A) 43998 (five digits) ---> 4.3998 as correct value.
Case B) 4399 (four digits) ---> 4.3990 as correct value, but parsed as 0.4399 because 0 has been removed when file was created.

Is there any way, like:

IF (NUM < 10000) THEN NUM = NUM / 1000 ELSE NUM = NUM / 10000

Or something like IF (Number_of_digits(NUM)) THEN ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no need for VB script, go this way:

open a syntax window, paste the following code:

```
do repeat vr=var1 var2 var3 var4.
compute vr=vr/10000.
end repeat.
save outfile="filepath\My corrected data.sav".
exe.
```

Replace `var1 var2 var3 var4` with the names of the actual variables you need to change. For variables that are contiguous in the file you may use `var1 to var4`.
Replace `vr=vr/10000` with whatever mathematical calculation you would like to use to correct the data.
Replace `"filepath\My corrected data.sav"` with your path and file name.

**WARNING**: this syntax will change the data in your file. You should make sure to create a backup of your original in addition to saving the corrected data to a new file.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Can you help me with the edited problem above?

Comment: Anyway, I ve this issue now:
`The only 
>recognized subcommands are: OUTFILE, KEEP, DROP, RENAME, MAP, COMPRESSED, 
>UNCOMPRESSED UNSELECTED y ENCODING.`

Comment: Given the update, you might do something like `COMPUTE V1 = V1/(10**TRUNC(LG10(V1))).` That assumes all the values are greater than zero though (so no zeroes and no negative values).

Comment: The issue you were having is because of a missing period at the end of my `save` command - now corrected above.

Comment: Re your other question - I like  @AndyW 's suggestion above, but if you want to use `if` conditions, your command would look like this: `if [something] [do something].` (no "then"). If you want to use "else"  - here's a nice quick tutorial about using `do if` in spss: https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-do-if-command/